# How can I select and transform items from a list in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following list:

```
$list = @('PONTEVEDRA:false:siAPP','MADRID:true:noAPP','MADRID:true:noAPP','PONTEVEDRA:true:siAPP')
```

I want to generate another list with the following content:

```
$transformedList = @('PONTEVEDRA:1:1:2:0','MADRID:2:1:3:0')
```

where {0} is the locality {1} the total of true {2} the total of false {3} the total of siAPP and {4} is the total of noAPP all with respect to its locality

How could I do it in powershell?

Comment: Count your entries e.g. using a loop. Also your example is wrong for Madrid, there is no entry that's `false`. In addition you might want to consider a better datatype unless there is a reason to make it text. A hashtable/psobject might serve you better and might make it easier to act on your data.

Comment: can you give an example of how to count the entries and a hastable with respect to the list?

Comment: `$results = @{}; @(1,2,2,4) | Foreach-Object { if($results[$_] -eq $null){ $results[$_] = New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Name" = $_; "Count" = 1} }else{$results[$_].Count++;}  }` naturally you'd have to adapt it. You might want to start out by just using `Write-Output` and actually counting the true/false numbers for your input. Using hashtables/objects will allow you to do something like `$transformedList[Madrid].TotalTrue` down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) (alias: group) is the perative cmdlet for this task.

Here's one way:

```
$SourceList = @('PONTEVEDRA:false','MADRID:true','MADRID:true','PONTEVEDRA:true')
$NewList = $SourceList | ForEach{
    $_ -match '(.+):(.+)' | out-null
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Loc' = $matches[1]
        'Bool'= $matches[2]
    }
} | Group Loc -pv loc | ForEach{
    $BoolSplit = $_.Group | Group Bool -NoElement
    '{0}:{1}:{2}' -f $loc.Name,
                     ($BoolSplit | ? Name -eq 'True').Count,
                     ($BoolSplit | ? Name -eq 'False').Count
}

$NewList
```

---

### Edit: Including summary information

If you break down the above code to see what's in the pipeline, you'll see that this code segment:

```
$SourceList | ForEach{
    $_ -match '(.+):(.+)' | out-null
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Loc' = $matches[1]
        'Bool'= $matches[2]
    }
}
```

Creates these objects:

```
Loc        Bool
---        ----
PONTEVEDRA false
MADRID     true
MADRID     true
PONTEVEDRA true
```

which, if grouped by `Bool`, will get the total counts of "True" and "False":

```
PS > $SourceList | ForEach{
>>     $_ -match '(.+):(.+)' | out-null
>>     [PSCustomObject]@{
>>         'Loc' = $matches[1]
>>         'Bool'= $matches[2]
>>     }
>> } | Group Bool

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    1 false                     {@{Loc=PONTEVEDRA; Bool=false}}
    3 true                      {@{Loc=MADRID; Bool=true}, @{Loc=MADRID; Bool=true}, ...
```

So to capture the intermediate object, modify the original code to create another collection. This segment:

```
$NewList = $SourceList | ForEach{
    $_ -match '(.+):(.+)' | out-null
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Loc' = $matches[1]
        'Bool'= $matches[2]
    }
}
```

becomes this:

```
$NewList = ( $SumList = $SourceList | ForEach{
    $_ -match '(.+):(.+)' | out-null
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Loc' = $matches[1]
        'Bool'= $matches[2]
    }
} )
```

Then, when you run the modified code, you've not only created `$NewList`, but `$SumList` as well. With that, you group and select:

```
PS > $sumList | Group Bool -NoElement | select Name, Count

Name  Count
----  -----
false     1
true      3
```

So, the full modified code would be:

```
$SourceList = @('PONTEVEDRA:false','MADRID:true','MADRID:true','PONTEVEDRA:true')
$NewList = ( $SumList = $SourceList | ForEach{
    $_ -match '(.+):(.+)' | out-null
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Loc' = $matches[1]
        'Bool'= $matches[2]
    }
} ) | Group Loc -pv loc | ForEach{
    $BoolSplit = $_.Group | Group Bool -NoElement
    '{0}:{1}:{2}' -f $loc.Name,
                     ($BoolSplit | ? Name -eq 'True').Count,
                     ($BoolSplit | ? Name -eq 'False').Count
}

$NewList

$sumList | Group Bool -NoElement | select Name, Count
```

---

### Edit3: Alternate summary method:

While the above would be good if you needed further access to your original data in object form, but if all you need are the sums mentioned, the following would probably more effecient and faster. It doesn't create another collection or list, but rather uses to refernce variables to keep a running total as the data is processed:

```
$SourceList = @('PONTEVEDRA:false','MADRID:true','MADRID:true','PONTEVEDRA:true')

[ref]$TrueTotal  = 0
[ref]$FalseTotal = 0

$NewList = $SourceList | ForEach{
    $_ -match '(.+):(.+)' | out-null
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Loc' = $matches[1]
        'Bool'= $matches[2]
    }
} | Group Loc -pv loc | ForEach{
    $BoolSplit = $_.Group | Group Bool -NoElement
    '{0}:{1}:{2}' -f $loc.Name,
                     ($TrueCount  = ($BoolSplit | ? Name -eq 'True').Count),
                     ($FalseCount = ($BoolSplit | ? Name -eq 'False').Count)
    $TrueTotal.Value  += $TrueCount
    $FalseTotal.Value += $FalseCount
}

$NewList
'Total "True"  : {0}' -f $TrueTotal.Value
'Total "False" : {0}' -f $FalseTotal.Value`
```

---

---

### Edit #2: Additional data

Same as before, the first thing you want to do is convert your data into objects. I took a slightly different tack this time -- not to confuse, but to show an alternate method. If your data is actually coming from a file, you would use [`Import-Csv`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Import-Csv?view=powershell-5.1) rather than [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv):

```
$list = @('PONTEVEDRA:false:siAPP','MADRID:true:noAPP','MADRID:true:noAPP','PONTEVEDRA:true:siAPP')

$ListObjects = $List | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ':' -Header ('Loc','locBool','AppInfo')
```

Which yields:

```
PS > $ListObjects

Loc        locBool AppInfo
---        ------- -------
PONTEVEDRA false   siAPP
MADRID     true    noAPP
MADRID     true    noAPP
PONTEVEDRA true    siAPP
```

And again, group on `**Loc**` :

```
PS > $ListObjects | group Loc

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 PONTEVEDRA                {@{Loc=PONTEVEDRA; locBool=false; AppInfo=siAPP; Count=2; Na...
    2 MADRID                    {@{Loc=MADRID; locBool=true; AppInfo=noAPP; Count=2; Name=MA...
```

And with the `Group` *property* of each of those, we can extract the data you want using the [`Where` *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_methods?view=powershell-7.2) available to collections:

```
$ListObjects | Group Loc | %{
    $BoolGroup = $_.Group | Group locBool -NoElement
    $AppGroup  = $_.Group | Group AppInfo -NoElement
    '{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}' -f $_.Name ,
                             $BoolGroup.Where{$_.Name -match 'true'}[0].Count ,
                             $BoolGroup.Where{$_.Name -match 'false'}[0].Count ,
                             $AppGroup.Where{$_.Name -match 'siAPP'}[0].Count ,
                             $AppGroup.Where{$_.Name -match 'noApp'}[0].Count
}
```

Output:

```
PS > $ListObjects | Group Loc | %{
>>     $BoolGroup = $_.Group | Group locBool -NoElement
>>     $AppGroup  = $_.Group | Group AppInfo -NoElement
>>     '{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}' -f $_.Name ,
>>                              $BoolGroup.Where{$_.Name -match 'true'}[0].Count ,
>>                              $BoolGroup.Where{$_.Name -match 'false'}[0].Count ,
>>                              $AppGroup.Where{$_.Name -match 'siAPP'}[0].Count ,
>>                              $AppGroup.Where{$_.Name -match 'noApp'}[0].Count
>> }
>>
PONTEVEDRA:1:1:2:0
MADRID:2:0:0:2
PS >
```

Note that becaue the `Where()` method returns a collection even when there is zero or one element -- and because collections have a `Count` property of their own, you have to specify the `[0]` array index to get the `Count` from the `BoolGroup` and `AppGroup` sub-groups. Without that, `Count` would only return `0` or `1` -- depending on whether or not therewere any elements in the specified grouping.

Comment: you are jesus christ, thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. I do love a good pair of hippie sandals... :D

Comment: How would you get the total of everything list, that is, how many false are there in total and how many true are there in total? true = 3 , false = 1

Comment: @zeros: See editied answer...

Comment: I have modified my question please take a look

Comment: I'm not doing your school homework for you, am I ???  :D WIll take a look...

Comment: I think I have it but how do you do it to compare and thanks for everything the truth

Comment: ok I just looked at it and it's the same as what I did thanks hehe